# Liquid crystal structure: Equivalent effect of alkoxy group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers, optical-properties

Consider a structure like this,

R - Cy - Cy - Ph - OR'

where Cy represents a cyclohexane ring, Ph is a phenyl ring, and R, OR' is alkyl group and oxygen bonded to different alkyl group.

If 2 linearly bonded fluorines on top of the phenyl ring are moved to either cyclohexane ring, do you get the same effect?
What "effect" means I'm not sure, but this is related to liquid crystals having  $\Delta\varepsilon=\varepsilon_{\parallel}-\varepsilon_{\perp}<0$.

My initial guess is that because cyclohexane rings have $\sigma\rightarrow\sigma^*$ transitions, resulting in lower birefringence $\Delta n=n_e-n_0$, the effect is the not the same. I'm also assuming the dipole will be different? This is an organic chemistry question but sort of physics related so i wasn't sure where to put this question.